# Условие if

Tags: c#

Как в условие указать значение. Что если нажата кнопка, то выполняется условие?

Comment: @Weyner, постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы, а лучше книжку почитайте. В самом С# нет никаких кнопок, а вот во всяких GUI библиотеках к нему есть, но их много: WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, etc. Какую конкретно вы используете, я не знаю.

Comment: 1. Какая кнопка? Вы говорите о клавише на клавиатуре, кнопке мыши, или контроле типа `Button` в каком-то из графических фреймворков?
2. Скорее всего, вы хотите не это, а нотификацию о нажатии. Расскажите лучше о вашей настоящей задаче.

Answer (score 1):

[KeyPressed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx) читаем.

Answer (score 0):

в теле метода-обработчика пишем

```
    switch(key)
    {
         case "smth":
              //
              break;
         case " htms":
              //
              break;
         default:
              //
              break;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Если вы пользуетесь MS Visual Studio, выбираете соответствующий обработчик этого события, и будет создана подпрограммка обработки этого нажатия.